# Can't seem to get setTimeout to work?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
var ExplodeFrame = 0;
var ExplodeTimeout;
```

All this part does it checks when a player hits lava. It works. see commented part for call to animation

```
if((Player.x  > Lavas[i].x && Player.x  < (Lavas[i].x + Lavas[i].width)) || (Player.x + Player.width  > Lavas[i].x && Player.x + Player.width < (Lavas[i].x + Lavas[i].width)))
  {
    if((Player.y   > Lavas[i].y && Player.y < Lavas[i].y + Lavas[i].height) || (Player.y + Player.height > Lavas[i].y && Player.y + Player.height < Lavas[i].y + Lavas[i].height))
    {
     ExplodeTimeout = setTimeout(DrawSpawnAnimation, 200); //this part is new and might not work
     Player.jumping = false;
     Player.velY = 0;
     Player.velX = 0;
     Player.x = Player.spawnX;

     Player.y = Player.spawnY;
     Player.playerColour = Player.colour;

    }
  }


}
```

this method does not seem to work for me?

```
function DrawSpawnAnimation()
{

ExplodeFrame++;
alert("current frame" + ExplodeFrame);
var explodeX = Player.x - 50;
var explodeY = Player.y - 50;

if(ExplodeFrame == 1)
{
ctxAnimation.drawImage(spriteSheet,0,2740,100,100,explodeX,explodeY,100,100);
}
else if(ExplodeFrame == 2)
{
ctxAnimation.drawImage(spriteSheet,100,2740,100,100,explodeX,explodeY,100,100);
}
else if(ExplodeFrame == 3)
{
ctxAnimation.drawImage(spriteSheet,200,2740,100,100,explodeX,explodeY,100,100);
}
else if(ExplodeFrame == 4)
{
ctxAnimation.drawImage(spriteSheet,300,2740,100,100,explodeX,explodeY,100,100);
}
else if(ExplodeFrame == 5)
{
ctxAnimation.drawImage(spriteSheet,400,2740,100,100,explodeX,explodeY,100,100);
}
else
{
ExplodeFrame = 0;
 clearTimeout(ExplodeTimeout);
  ctxAnimation.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
}
```

}

It should show an animation at 5 frames a second until its over. That's what I am trying to do.

Comment: Does your alert in DrawSpawnAnimation fire?

Comment: I could not recommend more, learning to use a proper debugger. It allows you to step through your code line by line as it executes and see exactly what is going on. Google Chrome Developer Tools on debugging: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: I'd suggest you also learn how to 'accept' peoples answers (click the tick outline) as you have asked 6 questions and have accepted none.

Comment: rearrange your code and put this function `function DrawSpawnAnimation()` before the code that calls that function `setTimeout();`, its probably an undefined error

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` only fires a function once:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

It sounds like what you're looking for is `setInterval`:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: please don't post stuff from w3schools, want to know why? read this: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: I have set it to interval, still nothing!

Comment: @intuitivepixel Ha!! w3schools isn't that bad for this simple stuff. But w3fools does make a good point. Won't do it again.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` runs your code once. It seems that you are looking for something that runs every 200 milliseconds. For that, use `setInterval`. It works in the way you are trying to use `setTimeout`. When you use `setInterval`, you clear it by calling `clearInterval`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, replace the if statements with

```
ctxAnimation.drawImage(spriteSheet,(ExplodeFrame - 1) * 100,2740,100,100,explodeX,explodeY,100,100);
```

Secondly, you only call the `DrawSpawnAnimation` method once. In order to actually see the animation you should call it repeatedly. Do that by adding setting another timeout at the end of `DrawSpawnAnimation`:

```
function DrawSpawnAnimation()
{
    ...
    if (ExplodeFrame < 5)
    {
         setTimeout(DrawSpawnAnimation, 20);
    }
}
```